# Not booting after installing Nvidia Driver from .run file

Tags: drivers, nvidia, ubuntu-gnome, tty, recovery-mode

I am using ubuntu gnome 16.04 lts and I tried to install the nvidia-370 drivers from the .run file provided for linux64 on the Nvidia website. While installing it through the command line I allowed it to change certain settings and modify the xcofing. It also modified a setting which would supposedly cause gdm to load the Nvidia drivers.
After rebooting, it went straight to the tty, which kept blinking and only allowed me to enter one letter every 4 seconds.
Of course I tried "purge nvidia*" from the recovery after enabling networking (which usually solved my problems), but since I didn't install it through the command line, it did not find anything.

What could I do to revert to using nouveau?
Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved: Just press F1 on boot, select Ubuntu Upstart, log in to the tty, go to the directory where the .run file was downloaded to, and run

```
sudo ./FILENAME.run -uninstall
```

then reboot.